# Identifying arrays with a band structure

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, data-analysis

I would like to identify arrays with a band like structure (first image) as compared to a more homogeneous structure shown in the homogenous image.

I have so far used some skewness and RMS techniques to test for this but it doesn't work well if the bands are evenly spaced. Are there any more refined ways of identifying such arrays in Python?

[image: Bands]

[image: homogeneous]

Comment: Well, this is off topic for this forum; you might try dsp.stackexchange.com or stats.stackexchange.com. That said, there is basically no other way except for devising one or more patterns, perhaps with adjustable parameters, and computing a goodness of fit for each one, and finding out what fits best. All the different methods amount to trying one family of patterns or another, and/or figuring out a more efficient way to assess goodness of fit. Good luck and have fun.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sns.pairplot`.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# The dataset: wages
# We fetch the data from OpenML. Note that setting the parameter as_frame to True will retrieve the data as a pandas dataframe.

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml

survey = fetch_openml(data_id=534, as_frame=True)

# Then, we identify features X and targets y: the column WAGE is our target variable (i.e., the variable which we want to predict).
X = survey.data[survey.feature_names]
X.describe(include="all")
y = survey.target.values.ravel()
survey.target.head()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

train_dataset = X_train.copy()
train_dataset.insert(0, "WAGE", y_train)

sns.pairplot(train_dataset, kind='reg', diag_kind='kde')
```

[image]